# What can I do to change a glass panelled wall?

Tags: walls, doors, safety, glass, child-safety

I've just moved into a house with a really ugly dated wall with 3 glass frosted panels and a door. It's not safety glass and with 2 small children I want to get this changed ASAP, but unsure what options I have. Any ideas greatfully received.

Thanks

Cheryl [image]

Comment: Imo this question as it currently is needs to be closed as either 'opinion-based' or 'decorating advice'. You need to figure out for yourself what you want to do with that opening and then, if you need help with how to achieve that, ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply remove it all and leave the opening, if the door function is not important here.

Looks like an opening a standard sliding glass door set would probably fit. Alternatively, a double-door (hinged) set.

Quick fixes for childproofing include clear plastic screwed over if the light is important - just the lower part or full height if baseball in the house is on the menu of activities to break windows. There's also adhesive film to contain broken glass (for storm-proofing and bomb-proofing) but I don't know how well it works on textured glass.

Answer (score 0):

Quickest would be remove the door and put ply or similar over the wall on both sides. That would be “safe”...

then take the time to plan the “best” solution, could be it could be removed entirely, needs checking as I’m only guessing it is not structural.